# OneLogin signout response missing signature

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, kentor-authservices, onelogin

I'm using Kentor AuthServices with IdentityServer3 to authenticate against OneLogin.  When calling logout OneLogin uses a SAML redirect binding on the response that isn't signed which is causing issues with Kentor AuthServices.

The SAML profiles specification section 4.4.3.4 states that:

> The message MUST be signed if the HTTP POST or Redirect binding is
>   used. The HTTP Artifact binding, if used, also provides for an
>   alternate means of authenticating the response issuer when the
>   artifact is dereferenced.

The example shown here: https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/examples/logout-response shows a signature with the redirect binding.

Is there a way to force OneLogin to return a signed logout response?

Comment: With the redirect binding, the signature is part of the URL, not the response message. Or - do you say that onelogin doesn't send any signature with the logour response at all?

Comment: Correct, OneLogin isn't sending a signature at all.  The URL in the response contains SAMLResponse and RelayState but not SigAlg and Signature as expected.